# How to get the current user id in the path

Tags: users, uri

I'm using the [Workspace](https://www.drupal.org/project/workspace) module and when the user goes on their '`SITENAME/user`', there's a link which leads them to all the nodes they have added.

The path of the link is '`workspace/<UID>`' for example '`workspace/1`' for admin. I'm trying to create another tab to do the same function but I can't figure out what path should I put. I tried '`workspace/%`', '`workspace/user`'. But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer for this myself. Used the [me aliases](https://www.drupal.org/project/me) module. And used the path '`SITENAME/me`'. Works perfectly

> Provides shortcut paths to current user's pages, eg user/me, blog/me, user/me/edit, tracker/me etc.
>
> This means logged in users no longer have to know/remember their uid, and it makes it easier to link to user-specific pages from a site help page (without resorting to using php to put $user->uid in the link).

Answer (score 0):

Have a peek at what workspace is doing itself: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/workspace/tree/workspace.module

You probably want 'workspace/%user/foo' as the menu link, as it will autoload the user by the id that's provided in the call (see https://www.drupal.org/node/224170)